# utf-8 validation for JSON payload

Tags: javascript, json, validation, utf-8

I have a JSON payload and I want to validate that decoded payload is UTF-8-encoded representations of the completely valid JSON objects.

I can validate the payload is a valid JSON or not, but I want to ensure that the payload has no special characters like "Ã¥".

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: Why?  Is `"\U+4053"` allowed? Why?

Comment: @Jasen because in our case, the payload should not have these characters.

Comment: well that' s easy, just don't put them in.

Comment: @Jasen payload is not generated by me. If the payload was being created by me, I could do it, "easily". I just have to check the incoming payload.

Comment: how come you don't care about the structure of the payload?

Comment: @Jasen I woke up this morning and said my friend to send me a random JSON payload and I want to validate that for pleasure. What does it matter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186284/discussion-between-bk-and-jasen).

Comment: it seems that you may be ignoring other important matters that should be addressed at the same time, and that is a distraction.

Comment: It seems like you are checking for text mishandling on the sender's part and you want a simple, early detection on the entire JSON document rather than a field by field detection in the resulting object graph. What's missing from the question, then, is the technology/code used to acquire the JSON and deserialize it into an object graph. Most technologies/libraries discard the document during deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

given that it already passes JSON validation and assuming that your validator actually works there's only 3 ways to put non-ascii characters in.

literal 
   so scan for bytes above 0x7F

hex escape
   so scan for '\x' followed by other than 0-7

and UTF-16 escape
  so scan for '\u' followed by 3 digit (hex) numbers above 007

Comment: \x and \X are not valid [JSON](http://www.json.org/) string escape formats.

Comment: well, only `\x` is (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159 section 7)  but trusing a validator to exclude `\X` seems reckless